# What solutions are available if I apparently want to access to a hidden data constructor?

Tags: haskell

I'm using a package that carries around things in a convenient ReaderT monad.  Their runReaderT/unwrapping function is in a hidden module.  I'd like to be able to unwrap it arbitrariy/manually with an arbitrary environment.  So I don't have any qualms with doing it manually -- however, the environment type has a hidden data constructor, so I can't generate an environment that will typecheck with runReaderT.

Is there any way I can get around this?  Or should I give this up as impossible and attempt to restructure my program?  I'm planning on deploying this project to a remote system with an automated build system so I'm not sure if I want to edit the source of the package directly/fork it.

In specific, I'm using [`scotty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.4.6), and I'm trying to emulate [`runActionM`](https://github.com/ku-fpg/scotty/blob/master/Web/Scotty/Action.hs#L34-L41) from the `Web.Scotty.Action` module.  I trying to emulate a page request and capture the results, and also to emulate a page request that normally has IO side effects.

Specific example:

```
-- LibraryPackage.hs
module LibraryPackage (SpecialReader) where

import Control.Monad.Reader

type SpecialReader a = Reader Env a
data Env = Env Int

runSpecialReader r = runReader r (Env 5)


-- Main.hs
import LibraryPackage

main = do
  let
    r = return 10 :: SpecialReader Int

  -- problem here -- cannot construct an `Env`
  print $ runReader r (Env 5)
```

Comment: to the author of my close vote -- the question I'm asking is really a specific question about the general haskell language itself, not about a specific piece of code.

Comment: Could you give [a self-contained example](http://www.sscce.org/) illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're pretty well and truly stuck. Here are the options

1. Talk to the package maintainer and see if there's another solution
2. Use `undefined` if you don't actually need meaningful values
3. Don't use this version of the library (cut and paste, or fork in **very** extreme cases)
4. If this is just a one-off, you could sacrifice a goat and try `unsafeCoerce`

Haskell doesn't let you do things like creating types your not supposed to. Imagine what cause there would be if you could pattern match on `IO` for example.

Comment: if I fork, is there a way specify cabal to download from a git repo or other uri instead of from its repositories from the cabal file?

Comment: @JustinL. If you fork you're not going to receive any updates or bug fixes that you yourself don't write. Are you sure you want to do this before even attempting to restructure some stuff?

Comment: @JustinL. In particular, if you email the package maintainer an explanation of why you need something, chances are he'll export it for you. Perhaps in Web.Scotty.Actions.Unsafe or something

Comment: @JustinL. You can still pull bug fixes and updates from the parent repo. The only difference between the fork and the parent is going to be a few additional commits in the fork that add whatever functionality OP wants.

Comment: @kqr Keep in mind that since this is just a case of exporting something extra, if the OP has a real use case it might benefit others if these changes wander back into the main repo,

Answer (score 2):

Many packages use the module system to provide safety guarantees or optimizations that would be impossible if the hidden objects were able to be used in arbitrary ways by client code (the most obvious example being `IO`!). The module system is *designed* to make it impossible to do what you're trying to do.

However, many packages also have "secret" exposed modules (often with `Internal` in the name) that export the hidden names anyway. These often won't show up in the official docs, but you'll see them in the source/cabal files.

If Scotty is such a package then you're in luck, but using an internal module is tricky. Treat them like the `unsafe*` family of functions; in general they cause things to go horribly wrong, and the onus is on you to make sure it won't in this particular case. After all, the constructor for `Env` may be deliberately hidden specifically to stop you running the monad stack on arbitrary environments because that would go wrong. Also, the package author is likely to not consider breaking changes to the internal module to be "backwards incompatible", so you may have to do forward ports of your code even on minor version updates to Scotty.

If there really is no module exporting the required constructor at all (not even a unadvertised one), then there's no way to get at it without changing the package's source code. You can ask for it to be exposed (publicly or as a back door), or fork the package, or try to redesign your code so you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue a few times and I haven't been able to find any other solution than copy-pasting the code you need into your own module and export the necessary funcs.

It is a pretty ugly solution but it does work in the lack of anything else.

Comment: I can't do this, because I need the types.  I can't just copy and paste my own definition of the types, right?

Comment: Well it really depends on where the types are defined. If they are defined somewhere where you can't load them in, then you would have to copypaste them as well. As said, ugly solution. :P

Comment: The types are in the definition of the monad, so I would also have to redefine the entire monad and everywhere in my code that uses it, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`unsafeCoerse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/Unsafe-Coerce.html). If the `Env` is a newtype over e.g. `Int`, then `unsafeCoerse 5 :: Env` should work (at least in `ghc` it is guaranteed).

It may or may not work for ADT.

```
shum@shum-lt:~$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :m + Unsafe.Coerce 
Prelude Unsafe.Coerce> data Env1 = Env1 Int String deriving Show
Prelude Unsafe.Coerce> data Env2 = Env2 Int String deriving Show
Prelude Unsafe.Coerce> unsafeCoerce (Env1 5 "hello") :: Env2
Env2 5 "hello"
Prelude Unsafe.Coerce>
```

Comment: Just for the record: "unsafe" in the name means that it can break everything. So use it only when there are no other ways, and make sure  you really know what you are doing

Comment: IIRC if GHC has optimized the data into a different representation due to how it's used (possible) you're very very screwed. It's only guarenteed with newtypes because they become the type the wrap, hence newtype not data

Comment: Don't do this.  It's really bad style.  And unsafe.

Comment: @jozefg @augustss, isn't that exactly what I wrote?)))
I think it is a valid answer, I don't know why you are downvoting. In theory you should never use `unsafe*` functions. But in practice sometimes you have to.

Comment: I'm upvoting this solely because I'm tired of people not exporting their constructors and running into exactly this problem.  If people don't want other users `unsafeCoerce`ing their data types, they should export enough that it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.mkNameG`. It's probably as bad as `unsafeCoerce`, but here is an example http://lpaste.net/91403 (the Minimize constructor is/was not exported).