# How to unhide the Data.IntSet.Base module in the containers package

Tags: haskell

I would like to write a function that operates directly on the Data.IntSet 'IntSet' datatype.

Looking at the source on hackage IntSet is being exported (i.e. there is an IntSet(..) at the top) however it is defined within Data.IntSet.Base which is a hidden module:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.IntSet.Base

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Data.IntSet.Base'
    it is a hidden module in the package `containers-0.5.0.0'
Prelude>
```

Is there some way I can unhide it?

I'm planning on writing a function:

```
match :: Int -> Mask -> IntSet -> IntSet
```

which returns a subset of the given IntSet such that all elements equal the input sans mask. There's no way I can see to write this function efficiently with the  exported api (for example, using filter or partition would be too slow for the large IntSet's I want to work with).

Obviously I could copy the source code out of the containers package but it would be nice if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of, or at least very related to, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724956/what-solutions-are-available-if-i-apparently-want-to-access-to-a-hidden-data-con

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is you can't in a general way.

If you just want that to play around (in an unportable way), you can download the `containers` package (`cabal unpack conntainers`) and move the module to the `exposed-modules` section in the cabal file and reinstall the package.

Comment: Ok that's not a bad approach, definitely cleaner than copy-pasting it into my project.